# Move a notebook from Phone to OneDrive

Tags: 8.0, onedrive, onenote

### Problem

I have a Windows Phone 8. Its OneNote app has two notebooks. One of the notebooks has "Phone" as its location, the other has "SkyDrive" (now OneDrive) as its location.

- Shaun's Notebook - Phone
- BigFont Notebook - SkyDrive

I would like to move "Shaun's Notebook" from its current location to SkyDrive (now OneDrive.) How do I do this?

### What I Have Tried

- I have looked for settings on the phone that allow me to move "Shaun's Notebook" to a different location.
- I have logged in to http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/my and looked for settings there.
- I have plugged my phone into my Windows 8.1 computer via USB. Then, I have looked for ways to move "Shaun's Notebook" both with the File Explorer and the Windows Phone App.

In all cases, I haven't found a way to move the notebook from "Phone" to "SkyDrive."

In Windows 8.1 there is a process for moving a notebook. We open OneNote, then choose File > Settings > Properties > Change Location. How do we do this with Windows Phone 8?

### The Big Deal

The big deal here is that I have dozens of notes in "Shaun's Notebook" on my phone. These are not backed up. These are not accessible from anywhere except my phone. If I were to lose my phone or if it were to die, it seems that I would lose all these notes. That's a very bad thing.

A workaround, of course, is to start taking notes only in "BigFont Notebook", because it is stored also in SkyDrive (now OneDrive). I'm afraid this doesn't solve the problem of backing up my existing notes.

### Some Research

> Unless you save your notes in the OneNote notebook that is automatically created on your Windows Phone device, all of your notes, complete with images and sound clips, will be synchronised to the cloud, most probably your SkyDrive account.
>   - [All About Windows Phone](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/features/item/15976_Making_the_most_of_OneNote.php)

This might be the source of the problem. "Shaun's Notebook" might be the one that OneNote "automaticaly created" and thereby does not sync with SkyDrive.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem on my iOS Notes app on my iPad. I had to just cut the entry, then paste it to a new note at the preferred destination. In your case, this is the OneDrive notebook. Even with a few dozen entries, you will be finished with the manual process before you get another answer.